# IIS can not see database server, but it's visible from visual studio development server! Why?

Tags: iis

I am using net 3.5 web services that use sql server 6.5 running on windows NT. Once again don't ask me why :)

Problem appears when I deploy webservice on my local IIS 5.0 
I use ABSOLUTLY the same connection string in both casses. I even caugth the string in break points when webservice is ran from IIS and when it's ran from visual studio and it is IDENTICAL! In next line of code is

```
connection.Open();
```

and in that line code braks, exception occures, but only in IIS case.
Connection string is with user name and pass with no Integrated secutiry key. 
The error I receive when using WS deployed on IIS is 
Server does not exist or access denied.
I checked the sql servers Profiler(yes, sql 6.5 has profiler called SQL trace:) to see if it's something with credentials, but it not even get up sql server.

It smels on some kind of network problem, or I don't know. It's verry wierd. Same server not visible from same computer. Only difference is that in one case WebService is runing on IIS and in other from Visual Studio. My admin doesn't have a clue.

I doubt, but, any ideas? :D

p.s. I posted this cuestion on stackoverflow, but then realised that maybe this is the more suitable place.

Comment: Um, I don't know.  I'm thinking there's a misspelling in your code somewhere...

Comment: The only thing that differs is address of webservice. web service that contacts the database has ABSOLUTLY SAME connection string in both casses!!
:/

Comment: Liar. According to http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions.aspx - .NET 3.5 does NOT WORK ON WINDOWS NT. Heck, windows NT is about 15 or so years old. NT 4 is WAY before year 2000 or so. It does not fulfill the requirements for .NET 3.5

Comment: ahahahahah :) take it easy. sql 6.5 is running on NT, not webservice. I said WS is running in IIS 5.0 and that's win XP. 
p.s. your link is magnificent :) hahahha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found!

It was trick to set Default protocol to TCPIP in SQL Client Configuration Tool in sql 6.5.
Originaly it is Named Pipes.

Also connectioon string needs this key Network Library=DMBSSOCN

Doubt anyone would need this but maybe there is someone :)